# Pushing a list of colors into colordialog.customcolors

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a list of colors i.e.: "1323523, 12342, 2354, 356234, 234234"

Each of these numbers stand for a color. I would like it so that when there is `colordialog.showdialog`, this list of colors shows up in the colordialog custom boxes.

this is how i am doing it currently, but for some reason the customcolors are not being added. i know for a fact that my array is good because i checked it.

```
Dim numberStrings = My.Settings.mytext1.Split(","c).Select(Function(x) x.Trim())
            ColorDialog1.CustomColors = numberStrings.Select(Function(x) CInt(x)).ToArray()
```

Comment: What colors do those numbers translate to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the documentation on the `CustomColors` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.colordialog.customcolors.aspx